# Equal alignment of two div borders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I build a layout using bootstrap, tried to build a table using divs
but i can't equalize the 2 divs borders to be correctly vertically aligned.

HTML:

```
<div id="p_table">
  <div id="h_tb" class="row">
    <div id="lt_h_tb" class="col-md-4">Starter</div>
    <div id="sub_h_tb_mid" class="col-md-4">Premium</div>
    <div id="rt_h_tb" class="col-md-4">Golden</div>
  </div>

  <div id="r_tb" class="row r_tb ">
    <div id="b_lr" class="col-md-4">
      <p><span>form $</span>1000</p>
    </div>
    <div id="b_lr" class="col-md-4">
      <p><span>form $</span>2000</p>
    </div>
    <div id="b_lr" class="col-md-4">
      <p><span>form $</span>3000</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="n_tb" class="row n_tb">
    <div id="b_lr" class="col-md-12">   
      <p><button type="submit" id="get_it" class="btn btn-success">Get IT</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#p_table {
  border-left:1px solid #ccc;
  border-right:1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

#h_tb {
  font-size:24px;   
  color:#000;  
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}
```

Image:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why not use an actual table?

Comment: Exactly. It seems to be tabular data you want to put there. Tables aren't bad for everything ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS

```
#p_table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#p_table > .row {
    display: table-row;
}

#p_table > .row > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

to style the divs like table cells